# Travis NUnit Run fails

Tags: github, continuous-integration, travis-ci

i have a github project which i'm trying to intergrate in to Travis CI. i'm really new to this. so on my travis.yml i have added like this

```
language: csharp
solution: MigrationRunner.sln
install:
  - nuget restore MigrationRunner.sln
  - nuget install NUnit.Runners -Version 3.4.1 -OutputDirectory $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/libs
script:
  - xbuild /p:Configuration=Release MigrationRunner.sln
  - mono $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/libs/NUnit.Runners.3.4.1/tools/nunit-console.exe $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/libs/MigrationRunner.Test/bin/Debug/MigrationRunner.Test.dll
deploy:
  provider: releases
  api_key: "79bd0a7b6294145bde09c390b2f5c03680c589b1"
  file: "MigrationRunner"
  skip_cleanup: true
  on:
    tags: true
```

and then tried to run travis but it gets error saying

> Cannot open assembly
>   '/home/travis/build/gayan85/MigrationRunner/libs/NUnit.Runners.3.4.1/tools/nunit-console.exe':
>   No such file or directory.

what was the wrong?